# Sympy Integrate is not showing the right answer

Tags: python, sympy

I want to `integrate(cos(3theta)/(5-4cos(theta)),(theta,0,2pi))` this expression whose
answer is `pi/12`. But sympy does not execute the integral correctly.

So, I replaced `cos(3theta)` with
`4cos(theta)*3-3cos(theta)`. Then I am obtained `-21pi/8`. Also, when I replaced `cos(3theta)` with
`cos(theta)` sympy executed the integral and gave `-pi/2`. Can anyone please elaborate why sympy is not giving the correct integral? What would be the right code to obtain the correct answer?

```py
from sympy import integrate, cos, pi, symbols

theta = symbols('theta')
sol = integrate(cos(3 * theta) / (5 - 4 * cos(theta)), (theta, 0, 2 * pi))
print(sol)
```

Output: `67*pi/24`

Correct output would be `pi/12`

Comment: Can you please show a reproducible code snippet demonstrating the issue you are describing?

Comment: Would it help if cut up the range for theta into chunks where `cos(3*theta)` is positive, and separate chunks where it is negative?